# AWS API Gateway: How do I make querystring parameters optional in mapping template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I can't seem to figure out how to create optional query string parameters using a mapping template within my resource's Integration Request.

My template looks like this:

```
{ "limit": "$input.params('limit')", "post_date":"$input.params('post_date')" }
```

I'd like 'limit' & 'post_date' to be optional. This template creates a querystring that looks like this when these parameters are not provided:

```
/myresource?limit=undefined&
```

When I'm expecting:

```
 /myresource
```

The [Docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#input-variable-reference) don't seem to cover this. I have found some example templates in the documentation that use a bash-like syntax to provide conditional functionality. I've tried testing the following but it will NOT validate in the AWS console:

```
        #set($limit = $input.path('limit'))
        { 
          #if($limit)"limit": "$input.params('limit')",#end
        }
```

Am I on the right track?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you should define all possible parameters and then handle `undefined` in your backend.

Comment: Are you using `Lambda` as a backend?

Comment: @napalm That's what I'm currently doing now. Really AWS?! That's lame. Lambda -> Yes

Comment: It's not lame really, the processing pipeline is JS based. It can't know if you didn't pass `undefined` in intentionally.

Comment: @napalm That must be the case. I'm handling this on the backend anyways. Thank you for your thoughts.

Comment: I have the same issue here. I am using API Gateway as a Proxy on top of Kinesis. So passing in undefined is not an option. I am sure there are other options.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you absolutely can do this in Api Gateway; although it does not seem to be well-documented!

In your question, you mentioned that this is a parameter; but you used input.path, which would normally refer to an element in the body of the POST request. The following should work:

```
#set($limit = $input.params('limit'))
{
#if($limit && $limit.length() != 0)
"limit": "$input.params('limit')"
#end
}
```

In terms of documentation, I found that the following page from AWS is actually pretty useful. It's tucked away in a section about mock endpoints, though:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-mock-integration.html

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to contribute, as Tom Kerswill's answer did not work for me.

I kept running into the issue where if I defined an optional parameter and didn't use it, I would get a JSON parse exception when calling the API.

How I got mine to work:

```
#set($hasOptional = $input.params("optionalParam") != "")
{
    "requiredParam1": $input.params("requiredParam1"),
    "requiredParam2": $input.params("requiredParam2"),
    #if(!$hasOptional )
    "optionalParam": null
    #end
    #if($hasOptional )
    "optionalParam": $input.params("optionalParam")
    #end
}
```

Running with ONLY the second 'if' statement did NOT work, I had to explicitly set the optional parameter to null if it didn't exist.

Also note the use of quotation marks, putting quotes around the entire $input... never worked for me. E.g.

```
"$input.params('limit')"
```

I had to write them out exactly like this:

```
"requiredParam1": $input.params("requiredParam1")
```

Hope this helps another frustrated AWS API Gateway user.